# Where to find `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer` or `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer` API document?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I can't find **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer** or **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer** API. I want to see list of methods or events before create my custom renderer.

[Official MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) shows a simple instruction for creating custom renderer, but does not give me a full specification about `ViewRenderer` class.

I could look into [Github source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs), but I do not want to know how `ViewRenderer` class implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my knowledge, if you want to see APIs of a class, you can select that class and press **F12**(or **Ctrl + left click**) to see APIs. Here is what I found:

**Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer** :

[image]

[image]

**Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer:**

[image]

[image]